Fetch Pending все время. Запрос уходит на сервер, но ответ просто не приходит
Такая проблема только с отправкой файла (jpeg) через FormData. Функция для отправки запроса:
export const HttpPostFile = async (path, body, headers = {}) => {
   const options = {
       method: "POST",
       headers: headers,
       body: body,
       credentials: "include"
   }
   console.log(options)
   let res = await fetch(serverUrl + path, options).then(r => console.log(r)).catch(e => console.log(e))
   console.log(1)
   return await res.json()
}

Сам вызов функции внутри хука, сама функция updatePhoto вызывается по клику на элемент:
const [updatePhoto, loading, error] = useFetch(async () => {
        let data = new FormData();
        let file = await fetch(newPhoto).then(r => r.blob()).then(blobFile => new File([blobFile], `user_${id}.jpeg`, { type: "image/jpeg" }))
        data.append(`users_photo`, file, `user_${id}.jpeg`)
        let res = await HttpPostFile(`/users/${id}/update_photo`, data, {"Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("access_token")}`})
        console.log(res);
        setPhoto(newPhoto);
        setPhotoChanged(false); 
        setNewPhoto(undefined);
    });

На сервер все приходит и обрабатывается как нужно (использую multer, но и до его использования ответа не было):
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"]
}))

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/users", userRouter);
app.use("/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/secure", secureRouter);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, async () => {
    console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', "[server]: server is working at http://localhost:5000")
})

Ендпоинт для загрузки фото:
async updateUsersPhoto(req: Request, res: Response) {
        console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', `[server]: POST request to /users/${req.params.id}/update_photo`)
        try {
            const decoded = await authController.verifyJWT((req.headers.authorization as string).slice(7)) as IJwtPayload
            res.status(200)    
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(`Error was occurred: ${e}`)
            res.status(401)
        }
    }

userRouter.post("/:id/update_photo", 
    userController.updateUsersPhoto,
    FileMiddleware.diskLoader.single("users_photo")
)


Что конкретно вы имеете в виду под фразой «ответ просто не приходит»? Вы тут наставили кучу console.log'ов (в том числе ломающих), что они выводят и срабатывают ли вообще?

Ну и да, фраза «ответ просто не приходит» сама по себе подразумевает отслеживание запроса через мониторинг сети в браузерных девтулзах — что там?

вот именно, что ни один лог не работает, в девтулзах вот так же пишет, что у этого фетча (update_photo) - статус pending. Payload есть, Response пустой

Если даже console.log(options) не срабатывает, то вы или делаете что-то не то, или смотрите что-то не то

Нет-нет) не работают логи только после самого fetch непосредственно. Сейчас ещё такая ошибка вышла в девтулзах (после таймаута на фетч):


Хотя на сервере корсы есть, другие запросы обрабатываются нормально

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.

res.status(200) — а вы кстати не отправляете ответ, ведь вы не вызвали ни send ни end

Точно, совсем уже плыву) спасибо за внимательность и ответ)

Ну и ещё имейте в виду, что этот ваш .then(r => console.log(r)) выбрасывает ответ, из-за чего переменная res всегда будет иметь значение undefined

Как правильно заметил andreymal, небходимо отправить ответ, а не просто назначить статус)
res.status(200).json(что-то там)

